# How to find subscribers specific to Business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, sfmc-business-unit, subscriber-key

I have 2 BU's in my account and single contact(email address) being part of both BU's.

I'm not able to find which contact belongs to which account Id , since MID field is not available in _subscribers ,_listsubscribers data view.

Is there an option to find business unit of a subscribers ?

[image]

Comment: The second one clearly comes from Salesforce - but what about the first Id, is it really in a completely different format? Maybe you could use that to differentiate where they came from?

Comment: you can also you the sent data view to see which BU is sending to which subscriber

Comment: There are 2 Business units . One BU, contacts enter via syncronized data extension and in other BU data enters via API .

Answer (score 1):

_Subscribers Data view is an Enterprise level entity.

In other words: Subscriber do not belong to any Business Unit, they belong to the account as a whole and are stored at Enterprise Level (Parent BU). Since this is always the same, the system consequently doesn't needlessly store that association of Subscriber <-> BU, it is implicitly clear.

This is also the case for All Subscribers list, which aggregates data of - among other things - _subscribers data view on the frontend.

Some quotes from the docs:

> Marketing Cloud stores subscribers that are in an Enterprise 2.0 account in the parent account, regardless of which business unit imports them
> [...]

> In an Enterprise 2.0 account, you can create subscriber attributes only in the parent account.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_subscriber_filters.htm&type=5

> [_subscribers] data view only returns results at the Enterprise level, and not for business units.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5

> Every subscriber in your account appears in the All Subscribers list.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_all_subscribers_list.htm&language=en_US

You could of course think of ways to mark your subscribers origin when they enter, but this is a custom process you have to implement and cannot be established from system data post-hoc.